# What is probability of guessing number between $(-\infty, \infty)$?

Tags: probability

Can I calculate probability that I can guess random whole number in interval $(-\infty, \infty)$?

I know it sounds impossible but if I have infinite attempts and infinite time I should be able to eventualy guess it right multiple times in long run.

Comment: Oh no. The probability of guessing any real number exactly is zero.

Comment: But why? If i get really lucky i can guess even 2 in row or not?

Comment: Two words: measure zero. If you don't know about measure theory or even uncountable sets, you may not understand fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the probability function of the distribution $p(n)$ used to generate the hidden number. However, as people here are trying to tell you, if you imply that the distribution is uniform ($p(n)=\mathrm{const}$), this distribution doesn't exist (at least with standard probability theory), so this problem is not mathematically sound.

Answer (score -1):

Yesn't.

If you require that all whole numbers occur with equal probability, the answer is no.
Since then you'd have for all $z\in\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{P}[z]=c>0$ for some $c\in(0,1]$.
But then
$$
1=\mathbb{P}[\mathbb{Z}]=\sum_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{P}[z]=\sum_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}c=+\infty
$$

However, if you don't require that all $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ occur with equal probability, this is possible.
For example say that $z$ occurs with probability $2^{-|z|-2}$ if $z\neq 0$ and with probability $1/2$ if $z=0$.
Then:
$$
\mathbb{P}[\mathbb{Z}]=\sum_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{P}[z]=\mathbb{P}[0]+2\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}2^{-n-2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}2^{-n}=1
$$